# Copy data from a local file to a remote SQL Server without BCP

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

Background information: The company I work at makes a database-backed product that has been around for decades. When a customer upgrades from a much older version, certain tables have changed so much that it can take a very long time to apply the model changes. In one case, it took 17 hours to do a single table. We have discovered that we can dump all of the table data to disk using the BCP command-line utility, truncate the table, apply the model changes, and load the data back in, all in far less time (the 17-hour case was reduced to more like 7 hours).

The problem: [BCP does not do truncation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/03/02/bcp-in-sql-server-2005-does-not-truncate-a-column.aspx). It *is* able to transfer the data to the server over a network, but it does not provide any way to do the equivalent of `set ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`. Trying to pre-truncate the data is unfeasible (it would kill the performance benefit we're trying to achieve) and BCP doesn't tell us which column(s) are the problem anyway. At the moment we've fallen back to the alternative of using `BULK INSERT`, with which we can set the `ANSI_WARNINGS` option.

My question is, does anyone know of a way to send the data over the network remotely, but still be able to set the option so that truncation is allowed? I guess I'm basically trying to re-implement part of the BCP utility, with a small change.

Comment: Just a thought, but have you considered renaming the existing table (with the data still populated in it), executing your script to create the table with the new fields, and then inserting the records from the original table to the new table (without having to incorporate BCP or Bulk Insert)? Would that be any less complex and still perform as well as the BCP-like solution?

Comment: I believe that solution was considered and didn't perform as well, and more importantly, you need the space in the database to be able to duplicate the entire table when you copy it back across. One table could be 400GB of data. When using BCP/BULK INSERT, that data can go to a different disk.